# String comparison in one line

Tags: c, strcmp

As a kind of exercise I want to implement the string comparison a short as possible.
The code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strcmp(const char* a, const char* b)
{
     for(;a && b && *a && *b && *a++==*b++;);return *a==*b;
}


int main ()
{
    const char* s1 = "this is line";
    const char* s2 = "this is line2";
    const char* s3 = "this is";
    const char* s4 = "this is line";


    printf("Test 1: %d\n", strcmp(s1, s2));
    printf("Test 2: %d\n", strcmp(s1, s3));
    printf("Test 3: %d\n", strcmp(s1, s4));
    printf("Test 4: %d\n", strcmp(s1, s1));
    printf("Test 5: %d\n", strcmp(s2, s2));

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
Test 1: 0
Test 2: 0
Test 3: 1
Test 4: 0
Test 5: 0
```

What is going wrong in the case of comparison of the string with itself?

**NOTE:**
I know that there is a shorter solution, but I want to find it by myself.

**EDIT:**
Compiler is `gcc` under Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you need `()` to seperate `&&`?

Comment: I run your code in vs2008 and the result is `0 0 1 1 1`.

Comment: Please don't call your functions the same as functions in the standard library if they don't provide the same functionality. You will break many things in subtle ways when you do that.

Comment: why not doing using <string> file? may be its a same name function as that in library thats why giving creepy results.

Comment: @AmoghDikshit, because (a) The OP wants to do this as an exercise and (b) this is `c` and not `c++` ;)

Comment: @Art write it as an answer. You are correct. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex heh. It was just a warning from the compiler in my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't call your functions the same as functions in the standard library if they don't provide the same functionality. You will break many things in subtle ways when you do that. Apparently that was the bug here.

To add a few more useful comments here. Use a while loop instead. Don't check for arguments being NULL, that's bad style and even if the for loop ends because of that, the return statement will crash anyway because it will dereference NULL.

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code with GCC-4.4.7 and it get same result.
GCC page describes optimization for `strcmp` http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/optimize.html

> GCC could optimize strcmp (and memcmp) where one string is constant to compare successive bytes to known constant ones inline.

Rename your function and you will get your expected result as below:

```
$ cc yourcode.c
$ ./a.out 
Test 1: 0
Test 2: 0
Test 3: 1
Test 4: 0
Test 5: 0
$ cc -D strcmp=strcmp1 yourcode.c
$ ./a.out 
Test 1: 0
Test 2: 0
Test 3: 1
Test 4: 1
Test 5: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you find two charactes that are not equal, you increment the pointers `a` and `b` nevertheless and then you return `*a==*b` so you return the result of comparing the characters *behind* the place where the strings differ. Better do it like that:

```
for(;*a && *b && *a==*b; a++, b++) ;
return *a==*b;
```

And **please, please** rename your function. it is evereything but strcmp.

**EDIT** that doesn't explain test case 4, but that's explained by the use of the function name `strcmp()` as the other answers tell.

Answer (score 0):

heres a correct strcmp

```
int             my_strcmp(char *str1, char *str2)
{
  int           i;

  i = 0;
  while (str1[i] || str2[i])
    {
      if (str1[i] != str2[i])
        return (str1[i] - str2[i]);
      i++;
    }
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: The keyword is **short**